# Why can I use dayJS in vuex actions but not to initialize states in a Vuex store?

Tags: state, nuxt.js, vuex, dayjs

I'm trying to set the initial month to the current month in state using the NuxtJS `dayjs` module.

Why can I use `this.$dayjs` in actions but not in state?
Shouldn't it be globally accessible?

And how could I initialize the current month in state?

```js
export const state = () => ({
  month: this.$dayjs().startOf('month'), //THIS LINE DOESNT WORK
})
export const mutations = { }
export const actions = {
  bindOngepland: firestoreAction(function ({ bindFirestoreRef, rootState }) {
    const month = this.$dayjs().startOf('month') // THIS LINE DOES WORK
    const nextMonth = state.month.add(1, 'month')
  }),
  setNextMonth({  }) {
  },
}
```

In this simplified example, I get an `undefined` error for line 2. `this` seems to be `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `state` is setup while the app instance is created, so the Nuxt instance wouldn't be defined yet. And `this` "works" (i.e., is your Nuxt instance) in the `bindOngepland` action because it's a *regular function* that has its context bound upon being called.

A workaround is for the component to call an action that initializes the state. In universal mode (or [`ssr: true`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-ssr/)), the store can provide a [`nuxtServerInit` action](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action) that is automatically invoked to initialize the state:

```js
// store/index.js
export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit({ commit }) {
    commit('SET_MONTH', this.$dayjs().startOf('month'))
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  SET_MONTH(state, value) {
    state.month = value
  }
}
```

In SPA mode (`ssr: false`), you'd have to dispatch the action explicitly:

```js
// store/index.js
export const actions = {
  init({ commit }) {
    commit('SET_MONTH', this.$dayjs().startOf('month'))
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  SET_MONTH(state, value) {
    state.month = value
  }
}

// MyComponent.vue
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('init')
  }
}
```